# Project tracker reflecting data by month

Tags: google-sheets

I'm working on building a project tracker to show how many contracts are in process, completed or missing BY MONTH to compare our progress annually. Most project trackers I've found require both a start and end date and will only show the number complete based on the current date.
I have a table set up with my Contract names and our staff will enter the Start Date and Finalized date in B1:D over in Columns F - M I have columns with each month and currently typing in "Here", In Process" or "FE" (for Fully executed/End).

**I'm trying to find a way to automate what fills into F-M based on what's been entered into column C:D. If there's no end date listed, I need it to continue to fill in "In Process" until an end date is entered.** I have done a little bit with Google Script and a lot with Formula, just can't find a solution either way to automate this part of the spreadsheet.
Here's a Screenshot of the project table
[image]

The End Goal it to have a chart that shows how many contracts were in process /have been completed by Month (so if 1 contract completed in January & 1 in February, a total of 2 would show up for February).
Here's a picture of my Report by Month
[image]

Comment: Share a link of sample google-sheet.

Comment: Here's a sample sheet https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KKIul06tEW89zyLIH5aqT7R69rA8HxtKuZiSmmHdNzc/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Here's one approach ([added to your sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KKIul06tEW89zyLIH5aqT7R69rA8HxtKuZiSmmHdNzc/edit#gid=916830695)) you may test out:*

```js
=map(C2:C25,D2:D25,lambda(c,d,map(F1:O1,lambda(Σ,if(or(c="",Σ=""),,
     ifs(--Σ<c,,and(c=--Σ,c<>d),"HERE",(isbetween(--Σ,c,if(d<>"",d,eomonth(today(),-1)+1),,0)),"In Process",and(len(d),--Σ>=d),"FE",1,))))))
```

[image]

Comment: WOW rockinfreakshow that is some incredible work! thank you SO Much!

Comment: I have 1 question I'm trying to solve with this solution, I want the first FE to show up in the column that matches the End date but it's showing up in the next month. For instance if the End date selected is Jan 2024, the first FE shows up in February instead of January. I tried adjusting the formula slightly with no luck, I just messed it up more.

Comment: the above shared formula shows `FE` in end date month already. As you can see in the above screenshot *row_3*, end date is Jan 2024 and FE is in Cell_J3 (for Jan 2024)

Comment: got it thank you! I see what happened on my end. my error. Thanks again, this is incredible work!